# Pushing a button on webpage via vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

So my overall goal is to scrape data from a table that is behind a security wall.  I have done the code to launch IE and input the security creditals however the code I have for clicking the Submit button isn't working.  The webpage I am working with is:

https://www.myfueltanksolutions.com/validate.asp

I have put the code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set i = New InternetExplorer
    i.Visible = True
    
    i.navigate ("https://www.myfueltanksolutions.com/validate.asp")
    
    
    Do While i.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    
    Loop

    Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set idoc = i.document
    
    idoc.all.CompanyID.Value = "CompanyID"
    idoc.all.UserId.Value = "UserID"
    idoc.all.Password.Value = "Password"

    Dim ele As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    
    Dim eles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Set eles = idoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
     

    For Each ele In eles
    
        If ele.Name = "btnSubmit" Then
            ele.Click
        Else
        End If
    
    Next ele

End Sub
```

Comment: `btnSubmit` is not a button, it is an image. `Set Eles = idoc.getElementsByTagName("img")`

Comment: Thank you, still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btnSubmit` is not a button, it is an image.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set i = New InternetExplorer
i.Visible = True

i.navigate ("https://www.myfueltanksolutions.com/validate.asp")


Do While i.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set idoc = i.document

idoc.all.CompanyID.Value = "CompanyID"
idoc.all.UserId.Value = "UserID"
idoc.all.Password.Value = "Password"

Dim ele As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim eles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
'Set eles = idoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
Set eles = idoc.getElementsByTagName("img")
 

For Each ele In eles

    If ele.Name = "btnSubmit" Then
        'ele.Click
        ele.parentNode.Click  ' click the <a> that contains this element
    Else
    End If

Next ele
End Sub
```

The submit button is just calling a javascript function, so you could skip finding the button all togeather.

```
idoc.parentWindow.execScript "submitForm();"
```